# Am I correct to use a one-way ANOVA for a control group and 8 treatment groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, anova

I need your help as I'm terrible with statistics.

I'm doing an experiment where we're looking to see if treating tendons with two different chemical agents at separate times, at different concentrations, treated at varying times, affects their tensile strength.

We had 5 tendons in each group (i.e. used 45 tendons total):

1. Control group - 5 tendons NOT treated with any chemical
2. 5 tendons treated with chemical A at 0.5% conc. for 30 minutes
3. 5 tendons treated with chemical A at 0.5% conc. for 24 hours
4. 5 tendons treated with chemical A at 1.0% conc. for 30 minutes
5. 5 tendons treated with chemical A at 1.0% conc. for 24 hours
6. 5 tendons treated with chemical B at 0.25% conc. for 30 minutes
7. 5 tendons treated with chemical B at 0.25% conc. for 24 hours
8. 5 tendons treated with chemical B at 0.625% conc. for 30 minutes
9. 5 tendons treated with chemical B at 0.625% conc. for 24 hours

Each tendon was loaded to failure using a machine, to determine their tensile strength. Each tendon was only used once.

What would be the best statistical test for this experiment, to determine if ANY of the independent variables (i.e. chemical A vs B, concentration of each chemical, treatment time 30mins vs 24 hours) results in a statistically significant difference in tensile strength?

We predict that all 8 treatment groups would result in a higher tensile strength than control, and that higher concentrations and longer treatment times would also result in a higher tensile strength compared to control and the lower concentration/treatment time groups.

I was thinking of simply using a one-way ANOVA, since all 8 treatment groups (excluding the control group) are independent of each other and I can think of them as 8 different independent variables?

Let me know what you guys think. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I would prefer a Bayesian multilevel model over a Frequentist ANOVA for this problem.